# Windows Alert: Incorrect pin entered too many times, Enter A1B2C3

Tags: windows, operating-system, windows-10

I have Windows 10 on an HP Probook. A few days ago, the login screen displayed:

> You've entered an incorrect PIN too many times. Please enter A1B2C3 to continue

Now I have to enter A1B2C3 every time before I can log in with my PIN.

I have read a few documents but didn't understand why this issue appears all of sudden. Why is this happening and what is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experienced errors with Microsoft Windows PIN in the past but never this one. The error would go away when I changed the PIN, so you could try that.

A quick Google search led me to [this Microsoft Forums question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/a1b2c3/ca42c5b7-3200-4480-b1b7-d71dbee20bc1):

> This login error happens when your current password has a problem, whether because of a Windows update or some other corruption

Comment: I have updated the password but still appears, That's why i have to search for more. By the way i am single user of this machine. So that's why i am confused about any type of corruption.

Comment: After changing the password 2 to 3 times. The problem is suddenly gone at that time.

Comment: Thanks @Trutix Changing the password one time worked for me.